# Deletion at end in linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

i am trying to write a simple program for deletion and insertion at the end of a linked list. I have managed to insert values at the end perfectly but I cannot understand what to do in deletion.

The delete function is `deleteend()`, display function is `display()` and insert function is `insertend(int x)` but I have problem only with `delteend()`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
};
node *head = NULL;
void insertend(int x)
{
    node *last = new node;
    last->info = x;
    last->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
        head=last;
    else
    {
        node *temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
            temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=last;
    }
}

void display()
{
    node *np=head;
    while(np!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<np->info<<endl;
        np=np->next;
    }
}

void deleteend()
{
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

int main()
{
    int data;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter value:";cin>>data;
        cout<<endl;
        insertend(data);
        cout<<"Enter more values?(y/n):";cin>>ch;
        cout<<endl;
    } while(ch=='y');
    cout<<"Your list is"<<endl;
    display();
    do
    {
        cout<<"Delete value from end?(y/n):";cin>>ch;
        cout<<endl;
        if(ch=='y')
            deleteend();
    } while(ch=='y');
    cout<<"Your list is"<<endl;
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note - it's much easier to operate at the end of singly-linked lists if you keep a `tail` reference in the first place. Having a non-null `head` sentinel node also simplifies your logic (at the cost of one extra value per list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain a reference to the node before the node you want to delete, so that you can set the pointers correctly.

Since you are only supporting delete from end, your function should look more like this:

```
void deleteend()
{
    // in case we have an empty list to begin with
    if (!head) {
        return;
    }
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        // our list was one element, so delete head and set our list to null
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // here, have a node that points to the head
    // and then have a node pointer to the next element
    // Traverse the list until you hit the end
    node *prev = head;
    node *end = head->next;

    while (end->next != NULL) {
        prev = end;
        end = end->next;
    }
    // once we're here, prev should be the second to last element
    // and end is the last element
    // so delete end and set prev->next to NULL
    delete end;
    prev->next = NULL;
}
```

This code can be adapted to delete any arbitrary node from the middle of the list.

Answer (score 0):

For deleteend(), you need to set what is the next to last nodes next pointer to null. This can be done using two pointers, one for the current node and one for the previous node, or by using a pointer to pointer. If using two pointers, in the case of a list with a single node, then there is no previous node, only the head pointer. biryee's answer shows the two pointer method.

Example code for pointer to pointer:

```
void deleteend()
{
node **ppnode = &head;     // ptr to head or a node's next pointer
    if(head == NULL)
        return;
    // advance ppnode so *ppnode points to last node in list
    while((*ppnode)->next != NULL)
        ppnode = &(*ppnode)->next;
    delete(*ppnode);       // delete last node
    *ppnode = NULL;        // set what was pointer to last node to NULL
}
```